# Should there be an article at the start of a factual sentence?

Tags: usage, vowels

____Umbrella is of no avail against a thunderstorm.

- An
- A
- The
- No article
- (I opted for option "d" since we are not talking about any single umbrella. We are talking generally. what's your opinion?)

Comment: There is no question that it should be _An_. A single object requires an article.

Comment: If I say 'The umbrella . . .  etc' I am referring to the concept 'umbrella' as an entirety. I am meaning that the invention called 'umbrella' is of no use. It is actually a stronger statement than the more usual 'An umbrella . . .  etc.'. The person who made up this question should allow of both answers.

Comment: You might use "The" if there is a specific umbrella being discussed.

Answer (score 2):

A/An - Indefinite article. Used when you aren't referring to a specific instance of the noun, but simply any single one of the noun. ('An' is used if the word immediately following it starts with a vowel sound, otherwise it's 'A')

The - Definite article. Used when you want to refer to a specific instance of a noun. Usually the noun will have been referenced previously. (Or, more rarely, as outlined by Nigel J: "If I say 'The umbrella . . . etc' I am referring to the concept 'umbrella' as an entirety. I am meaning that the invention called 'umbrella' is of no use.)

No article - Used for plurals, uncountable nouns and proper nouns. For example, "Umbrellas are of no avail against a thunderstorm", or "Umbrella is of no avail against a thunderstorm" if you had decided to name your coat Umbrella.

For this specific question without any more context, it technically could be 'An', 'The' or no article but it is very likely that it would be 'An'. This would refer to refer to the general inability of any single umbrella to hold out against a thunderstorm.

'A' is definitely incorrect as 'umbrella' starts with a vowel sound. You could add an adjective to make it work: "A small umbrella is of no avail against a thunderstorm.